# Alias for sys.tables in SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I'm using a poorly written application that's connected to a server where the case sensitive `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2` collation is used. The application for some reason tries to reference `sys.Tables` (note the capital T) instead of `sys.tables` causing it to fail.

Is there any semi-reasonable way to create a `sys.Tables` alias that simply points to sys.tables? Or is there another way to approach this *other* than fixing the application?

### Environment

- MS SQL 2016 SP1 (13.0.4199.0)
- Windows 2012 R2
- App connects via a .Net connector/framework

Comment: Collation is set at the database level, not the connection level... are you certain you're looking at the correct source of the problem?

Comment: @JiggsJedi: regardless of the terminology the OP used, wouldn't the problem manifest in the same way? i.e. if the database has a case sensitive collation, trying to reference the object as `sys.Tables` would result in an "object not found error".

Comment: @JiggsJedi I phrased my question poorly (I just edited it). It's connected to a **server** where the collation is case sensitive. The application however improperly references `sys.Tables`. Unfortunately I can't change the server collation since it's used by other apps that depend on that being the default collation.

Comment: Indeed, but its not the application or connection at fault here; and understanding the root cause yields different solutions.  The results are the same, absolutely I agree with you, but the fix is not.

Comment: @jak119 -- in that case, I do not believe there is a way to create a synonym for a system table.  Perhaps there are other SQL minds here who can think of a way, but I do not know of one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Realizing that's messy I tried it anyways and got a permission denied error even with the SA role.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you can't create objects in the `sys` schema, so, fix the app (you should always absolutely match case 100%) or do the harder thing of changing the collation. If it's server level see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx. Even if you do that to buy time, **fix the app**.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server collation is not set at the connection level.  It is set at the server/database level.

I would check your server/database first...

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));
```

or

```
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;
```

View Collation Information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx

And if necessary alter the collation (after testing of course).

Set or Change Collation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms175835.aspx